# How can I make a batch file that automatically builds, links and executes a .asm file?

Tags: assembly, masm

I am working with DosBox emulator in my university. We build .asm files with MASM. I am extremely tired of having to build my .asm file every time with masm, then pressing enter 4 times, then entering link .obj, then enter 4 times. Then running the actual .exe. I wanted to automate this, and after searching for a while, I understand I need to make a batch file. It currently looks like this

```
@echo off

set arg1=%1
masm %arg1%.asm
%SendKeys% ("echo off{ENTER}")
%SendKeys% "echo off{ENTER}"
%SendKeys% "echo off{ENTER}"
%SendKeys% "echo off{ENTER}"
link %arg1%.obj
%SendKeys% "echo off{ENTER}"
%SendKeys% "echo off{ENTER}"
%SendKeys% "echo off{ENTER}"
%SendKeys% "echo off{ENTER}"
%arg1%.exe
%SendKeys% "echo off{ENTER}"
```

The SendKeys part doesn't work. When I searched online I was way overwhelmed by what I've found. I just want a simple way (if there is one) to simulate the four enter key pressed I have to manually do every time.

Comment: Shouldn't `masm` have an option to not be interactive?

Comment: First time I hear about that. I've been googling that for the past 20 minutes, I was unable to find how to change that option. If you could tell me where would I be able to change that I'd be very grateful.

Comment: You are a lifesaver! I have been literally searching for 3 hours over this. I guess it's one of those things that's so obvious and simple nobody really asks about it. We don't cover shell programming in the course, I am sorry this is such a dumb question.

Comment: If you spend 3 hours researching this, it's not a dumb question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place a semicolon `;` on the end of `masm.exe` and `link.exe` command lines to make the programs use the default file names for the prompts.